# Passing same callback to different attr in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I want to increase jQuery any attribute number by 1 lets say.

For example

```
<label for='question_1' class='question_content_label'>
<input type='text' id='question_1' class='question_content'>
```

I want to increase its id by 1 so it becomes

```
<label for='question_2'>
<input type='text' id='question_2'>
```

I thought i would do in jQuery like this:

```
$('body').find('.question_content').attr('for',function (index,name){
            return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch,n){
                return Number(n) + 1;
                console.log(n);
            });
        });

$('body').find('.question_content_label').attr('for',function (index,name){
            return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch,n){
                return Number(n) + 1;
                console.log(n);
            });
        });
```

I don't want to repeat this:

```
function (index,name){
            return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch,n){
                return Number(n) + 1;
                console.log(n);
            });
        };
```

I thought creating function like this

```
function increment_attr_number(index,name){
            return name.replace(/(\d+)/, function(fullMatch,n){
                return Number(n) + 1;
                console.log(n);
            });
        };
```

And passing like this:

```
$('body').find('.question_content_label').attr('for','increment_attr_number');
```

but it don't work

Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference, not a string representation of it

```
$('body').find('.question_content_label')
         .attr('for', increment_attr_number);
```